# TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined in nodejs nodemon

Tags: reactjs, npm, server, split, nodemon

[error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yABiW.png)

react/node.js
i don't know what is the problem. It says that their is an error in nodemon. But, I can't find out the problem. 
Help me please.

```
index.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:4)
    at Object.../node_modules/nodemon/lib/utils/index.js (index.js:95)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.<anonymous> (run.js:3)
    at Object.../node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/run.js (run.js:459)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.../node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/index.js (index.js:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    ...
```

here is the code

```js
var noop = function () { };
var path = require('path');
const semver = require('semver');
//here is the problem. There is a 'split'.
var version = process.versions.node.split('.') || [null, null, null];

var utils = (module.exports = {
  semver: semver,
  satisfies: test => semver.satisfies(process.versions.node, test),
  version: {
    major: parseInt(version[0] || 0, 10),
    minor: parseInt(version[1] || 0, 10),
    patch: parseInt(version[2] || 0, 10),
  },
  clone: require('./clone'),
  merge: require('./merge'),
  bus: require('./bus'),
  isWindows: process.platform === 'win32',
  isMac: process.platform === 'darwin',
  isLinux: process.platform === 'linux',
  isRequired: (function () {
...
```

Comment: Could you please show us the code? The error means that the string that you're trying to split is not defined, and we need the code to see why.

Comment: I changed my post.

Comment: Help me please..ㅠ ㅠ

Comment: Could you do console.log(process.versions.node) and show us the result

Comment: the result is undefined.

Comment: How about just console.log(process.versions)

Comment: i tried console.log(process), and i found  versions:{ }
There is nothing in versions.. What does it mean?

Comment: So what's the nodejs version that you actually installed? Do you remeber?

Comment: "@types/node": {
      "version": "13.11.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/node/-/node-13.11.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-uM4mnmsIIPK/yeO+42F2RQhGUIs39K2RFmugcJANppXe6J1nvH87PvzPZYpza7Xhhs8Yn9yIAVdLZ84z61+0xQ=="
    },

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "5.1.0",
    "nodemon": "2.0.2"
  }

Comment: check the updated version

Comment: i updated. but there is no change...

Comment: I mean check my answer down there and try process.version not versions

Comment: i checked that process.version is a empty value

Comment: 1. open your shell. 2. type in `node` . 3. Give us the output (remember to strip out sensitive info.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the version, go for the `process.version` instead of `process.versions` property.

This is how `process` should look like.

```
process {
  version: 'v12.16.2',
  versions: {
    node: '12.16.2',
    v8: '7.8.279.23-node.34',
    uv: '1.34.2',
    zlib: '1.2.11',
    brotli: '1.0.7',
    ares: '1.15.0',
    modules: '72',
    nghttp2: '1.40.0',
    napi: '5',
    llhttp: '2.0.4',
    http_parser: '2.9.3',
    openssl: '1.1.1e',
    cldr: '36.0',
    icu: '65.1',
    tz: '2019c',
    unicode: '12.1'
  },
  arch: 'x64',
  platform: 'darwin',
  release: {
    name: 'node',
    lts: 'Erbium',
    sourceUrl: 'https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.2/node-v12.16.2.tar.gz',
    headersUrl: 'https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.2/node-v12.16.2-headers.tar.gz'
  },
```

Comment: 1. open your terminal / shell. 2. type in `node` . 3. Give us the output (remember to strip out sensitive info.)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to split a string with a separator that is not present.
In example

```json
...
  ares: '1.15.0',
  napi: '5',
...
```

If you're missing values, try to replace with 0, instead of default to null.